# __faststorefence over _ReadWriteBarrier

Tags: c++, windows, rdtsc

I've come across something interesting. I've noticed that when I use __faststorefence in my timing function, I get more consistent results compared to when I use _ReadWriteBarrier. Here's the basic structure of my timing function

```
__forceinline static uint64_t ReadTime() {
_mm_lfence();
__faststorefence(); // Previously used _ReadWriteBarrier
const uint64_t result = __rdtsc();
_mm_lfence();
__faststorefence(); // Previously used _ReadWriteBarrier
return result;
```

}

Could someone explain why __faststorefence might be providing more consistent timing results compared to _ReadWriteBarrier? thanks !

Comment: According to the docs (see Google), they do different things.  To see exactly what, examine the disassembly in both cases (Visual Studio will let you do that).

Comment: Looks like a comparison between `std::atomic` and `std::mutex`. I wonder why do you need to go so low-level.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm not sure what you're driving at.  There's no locking going on here.

Comment: @PaulSanders all those *lock*s are fences under the hood. An *opaque function* is essentially a function who calls a fence during its execution. Adding some structure and abstraction to the raw material brings safety measures to user code. Otherwise those low-level calls can hinder code maintenance.

Comment: @Red.Wave OK, sorry, let me try again.  I don't understand why you're talking about `std::mutex`.

Comment: @PaulSanders now that you mentioned I am not sure about that. I need to check which higher level sync object, each instruction can implement. Because there are half a dozen of them.

Comment: @Red.Wave Okies.  Windows has `CreateMutex`, it probably uses that, although there are other alternatives.

Comment: @PaulSanders I mean these kind of primitive function calls should only matter when implmenting something akeen to `barrier` or `mutex`, but I guess this is not the case here. I am not going to produce any more noise anyhow.

Comment: @Red.Wave OK, we're good.